# Flex для button элементов

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="collection">
        <div class="collection__item">
            <h2 class="collection__heading">New Chair Collection 2022</h2> 
            <a class="collection__button" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>               
        </div>
        <div class="collection__item">
            <h2 class="collection__heading">Lamp Desk</h2>
            <a class="collection__button" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collection__item">
            <h2 class="collection__heading">Modern Chair Collection 2022</h2>
            <a class="collection__button" href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Есть секция с текстом и кнопкой. Все элементы распологаю с помощью flex
Как расположить кнопки в один ряд?

&__item
background-color: #E5E6E6
width: 350px
height: 449px
display: flex
flex-direction: column
justify-content: flex-start
// align-items: flex-start

```
&__button
    width: 114px
    height: 37px
    margin-top: 21px
    margin-left: 53px
    background: #1C1B1B
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px rgba(53, 110, 173, 0.2)
    // border-radius: 10px            
    color: #fff
    font-weight: 600
    font-size: 14px
    line-height: 60px
    display: flex               
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center    

&__heading
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans'
    font-weight: 400
    font-size: 30px
    line-height: 40px
    color: #282828
    margin-top: 50px
    margin-left: 31px
```

Comment: Покажите ваши стили, а так же то, что получается сейчас и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вот

```
.collection{
  display:flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Загрузил свой вариант - https://postimg.cc/N531fj3z  Нужно чтобы вторая кнопка располагалась также как и все остальные.

Comment: Тогда задайте для .collection__heading фиксированную высоту